# Fermat’s Two Squares for polynomials

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there an analog of Fermat’s Two Squares theorem over polynomial rings $\Bbb Z[x]$ by considering a version for non-negative polynomials?

Fermat two squares says primes $p$ is sum of two squares iff $-1$ is quadratic residue mod $p$. Is there a sum of two squares formulation over polynomial rings using quadratic residues?

Comment: Do you consider Fermat's Two Square Theorem to be the theorem that characterizes the prime numbers that are sums of two squares or the integers that are sums of two squares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}$Yes. From [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/82294/297), I learn of the following result of [Davenport, Lewis and Schinzel](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=163880):

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that every
>   arithmetic progression contains an integer $n$ for which $f(n)$ is a
>   sum of squares, then $f(x) = u(x)^2+v(x)^2$ where $u$ and $v$ are
>   polynomials with integer coefficients.

In particular, if $f(n)$ is a sum of squares for all $n$, then $f(x) = u(x)^2+v(x)^2$.

---

I believe what actually comes out of the proof is the following criterion. Write $f(x) = c g(x)^2 \prod_j h_j(x)$ with $c \in \QQ$ and the $h_j$ distinct monic irreducible polynomials. Let $K_j$ be the field $\QQ[\alpha]/h_j(\alpha)$. Then $f(x)$ is a sum of squares if and only if

- $c$ is a sum of squares and
- $\sqrt{-1}$ is in the field $K_j$ for all $j$.

The point is that, by a theorem of Bauer (see e.g. [Theorem 2.6 here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/249BPage/handouts/cfthistory.pdf)), if $\sqrt{-1}$ is NOT in $K_j$ then one can find a prime $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ such that $h_j$ has a root $\bar{u}$ mod $p$. By some elementary arguments (see the paper) one can lift $\bar{u}$ to an integer $u$ so that $f(u)$ is divisible by $p$ exactly once, showing that $f(u)$ is not a sum of squares.

If your goal were to use this to check that a given polynomial is a sum of squares, you'd want an effective version of Bauer's theorem. This is more or less the same as an effective version of the Cebatarov density theorem. Such exist, but there are better ways to check whether one number field contains another.

More precisely, consider the question of whether $L$ contains a subfield isomorphic to $K$, for $K$ and $L$ number fields. My understanding (and this is NOT an area I am very knowledgeable about) is that one first generates lots of primes $p$ in search of a prime which splits in $L$ but not in $K$. If one finds such a prime, the answer is "NO" and you are done. However, I believe that, if the search fails, it is worth switching to other methods long before one has searched far enough for the failed search to constitute a proof that $K \subseteq L$.

Comment: Why not say $f(x)$ is a sum of two squares in ${\mathbf Z}[x]$ if and only if $f(n)$ is a sum of two squares in ${\mathbf Z}$ for all $n \in {\mathbf Z}$? Or is there a situation where the weaker hypothesis about all arithmetic progressions can be checked more easily?

Comment: @KConrad Edited to point out this implies your statement. I was copying what the Mathscinet reviewer wrote, which is pretty close to what DLS wrote. I just went through the DLS proof, and the weaker condition is what comes up naturally there. If I were to guess why they phrased it this way, I would guess that it is partly the desire to state the strongest result, and partly because it is surprising -- I would have guessed that one would need a set of primes of positive Dirichlet density to force something like this.

Comment: Does one has to check from $n$ from $1$ to $\infty$ and see if $f(n)$ is a sum of square to decide? Seems like there should be something different?

Comment: @Arul I added an edit to address this question to some extent.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ here?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}_j[\alpha]/h_j(\alpha)$ is the field $\mathbb{Q}$ with a formal root of the polynomial $h_j(x)$ adjoined.

Comment: Lets say $f(x)$ is irreducible. Then we are looking for if $\sqrt{-1}$ is in $\QQ[\alpha]/f(\alpha)$. Seems like a doable problem (in terms of complexity) since the corresponding version of identify qudratic residues modulo primes is I believe in $P$.

Comment: Is the corresponding problem hard for $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. At Arul I don't think it's hard in practice; Magma and SAGE both do much more complicated things with number fields all the time. But at this point you really should be asking a new question.

Comment: David, any guesses on this for the other binary forms (positive, primitive) where rational representation of an integer implies integral representation, including two non-principal, $$ x^2 + y^2, x^2 + 2 y^2, x^2 + x y + y^2, x^2 + x y + 2 y^2, x^2 + x y + 3 y^2; $$ $$ 2 x^2 + x y + 2 y^2,  2 x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2.  $$

Comment: @WillJagy Theorem 2 of the paper says "yes" if you ask for $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ to have rational coefficients. So the question is whether you can get from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ under the same circumstances that you can get from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: David, thanks. I'll need to check. This comes from Pete Clark's project generalizing Serre's proof in his little book, Pete calls it Aubry-Davenport-Cassels. It fits this question pretty well.

Comment: @WillJagy If you look at the proof in Section 5 of the paper, it clearly generalizes to $K$ of class number $1$. Not sure about forms like $x^2+5 y^2$.

Comment: David, I'm reading Pete's first paper on this, I'm not entirely sure either. It appears that I worked out all his Euclidean (positive) forms but not the binary A.D.C forms, which is a weaker requirement.