# univariate integer version of Hilbert's 17th problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, polynomials, sums-of-squares

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ with integer coefficients such that $f(x)\geqslant 0$ for all real $x$. Is it necessarily true that there exists an integer $N(d)$ such that $N(d)\cdot f$ is a sum of squares of polynomials with integer coefficients?

This is true if $\deg f=2$ (for $N(2)=2$, moreover, a non-negative polynomial $ax^2+2bx+c$ with integer $a,b,c$ is a sum of squares of integer polynomials) and true if the coefficients of the squared polynomials are allowed to be real (or rational).

**Update.** Since this is not entirely obvious, let me add a proof that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients such that $f\geqslant 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is a sum of squares of rational polynomials.

**Proof.** Induction in $2n=\deg f$. Base $n=0$ is clear. Induction step.
If $f(x)=cx^{2n}$, we may write $c=a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+a_4^2$ for rational $a_i$'s, so $f=\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i^2 c^{-1} f=\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i^2 (x^{2n}+\ldots)$ that reduces the question the case when $f$ is monic.

Next, we may suppose that $f$ is irreducible and strictly positive on $\mathbb{R}$, since if $f=\prod f_j^{k_i}$ is a factorization onto irreducible monic rational polynomials, we have for each $i$ either $2|k_j$ or $f_j>0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (since $f_j$ and $f_j'$ are coprime, thus the real roots of $f_j$ are simple and distinct for different values of $j$). So, using induction we represent each $f_j$ for which $k_j$ is odd as a sum of squares (of rational polynomials) and expanding the brackets we represent $f$ itself.

Since $f$ is strictly positive, we get $g:=f-cx^{2n-2}-c>0$ for a small rational $c>0$. Denoting the сomplex roots of $g$ by $p_j\pm iq_j$, we write $$g=\prod (x-p_j-iq_j)\cdot \prod (x-p_j+iq_j)=(A+iB)(A-iB)=A^2+B^2,$$ where $A=x^n-(\sum p_j)x^{n-1}+\ldots$ and $\deg B\leqslant n-1$. Approximate $A$ by a rational polynomial $A_0$ so that $\deg (A-A_0)\leqslant n-2$. This is possible since $\sum p_j$ is half the sum of roots of $g$, thus it is rational. We get $A_0^2=A^2-C$, where $\deg C \leqslant 2n-2$ and the coefficients of $C$ may be made arbitrarily small. This yields $$f-A_0^2=(g-A^2)+C+c(x^{2n-2}+1)=B^2+(C+c(x^{2n-2}+1))\geqslant 0,$$ and we may apply the induction proposition for $C+c(x^{2n-2}+1)$.

Another question which arises here is whether the number of squares may be uniformly bounded and if it can, what is the minimal number of squares which is enough.

Comment: How do you write $x^2+x+1$ as a sum of squares of integer polynomials? Or more generally any nonnegative polynomial with an odd coefficient of $x$?

Comment: The page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14456/sum-of-squares-in-ring-of-integers shows problems can occur for an analogue of this question with $\mathbf Z[x]$ replaced by the ring of integers in a number field. A lesson is that sums of squares for *fields* (of rational functions, of algebraic numbers) are better behaved than for *rings*.

Comment: @Wojowu oops, sorry, this is true for $ax^2+2bx+c$ only. I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: By taking derivative one can see that $2\mid N(d)$ is a must.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Yes. Possibly, any non-negative polynomial of the form $\sum a_i x^{2i}+\sum 2b_i x^{2i+1}$ is a sum of squares?

Comment: What about $f(x)=p(x,x+1)$, where $p(x,y)$ is the Motzkin polynomial $1-3x^2 y^2+x^2 y^4+y^2 x^4$? This is promising since $f$ is the sum of two squares of real polynomials, but neither $f$ nor $2f$ nor $4f$ is the sum of two squares of integer polynomials.

Comment: @MattF. It may be particularly promising, but for any fixed polynomial $f$ there exists $N>0$ such that $Nf$ is a sum of squares

Comment: @MattF. I do not know which $N$ works for this $f$, but see the update.

Comment: Working through one step of your procedure, I find $$\begin{align}\frac{P(x,x+1)}{2}=&\left(x^3+\frac32 x^2-\frac8{15}x-\frac35\right)^2\\ &+ \frac{49}{60}x^4 + \frac95 x^3+\frac{116}{225}x^2 - \frac{16}{25}x + \frac7{50},\end{align}$$which is enough to convince me

Comment: Related to your updated comment, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2976.pdf.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: You also want $g$ be squarefree. I've implemented your proof in SageMath and here is representation of Matt's example (modulo representation of positive rational coefficients):
$$P(x,x+1) = 2\big(x^3 + \frac32 x^2 - \frac12 x - \frac12\big)^2 + \frac32 \big(x^2 + x - \frac7{16}\big)^2 + \frac5{16} \big(x + \frac12\big)^2 +\frac{ 69}{512}.$$

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev thank you! Where do I use that $g$ is squarefree?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I thought you want $p_j \pm iq_j$ distinct, but now I see that this is not needed. In general, your proof looks somewhat overengineered to me - I have a gut feeling that there must be a simpler construction.

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82046/about-integer-polynomials-which-are-sums-of-squares-of-rational-polynomials).